# Camunda populate data at StartEvent / when starting a process

Tags: camunda

I am new at Camunda and just started learning. I am trying to populate a drop down list at the startEvent. I have the drop down in the embedded form like this.

```
<select cam-variable-name="PRODUCT_TYPE"
        cam-variable-type="String"
        cam-choices="AVAILABLE_PRODUCT_TYPES">
</select>
```

I do not know where to implement the java delegate with a code that should look similar to this.

```
Map<String, String> productTypes = new HashMap<String, String>();
productTypes.put("001", "Notebook");
productTypes.put("002", "Server");
productTypes.put("003", "Workstation");

execution.setVariable("AVAILABLE_PRODUCT_TYPES",  
  objectValue(customerData)
    .serializationDataFormat(SerializationDataFormats.JSON)
    .create());
```

Listeners do not work for startEvent. I have tried camunda:formHandlerClass extension. That did get invoked but it resulted in a blank form being printed since createStartFormData was returning null.

Please point me in the right direction.

Comment: I have also tried using ExecutionListener But it is not getting invoked

Comment: ExecutionListener with event="start" gets invoked when the startEven is executed .. i.e. when i press start process

Comment: Do you get any errors? When you add a simple variable(string) this way, does it work?

Comment: adding the variable is not the problem. The event does not get executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a listener with the above code on the Process itself like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3awr.png).